# Spring: open word/excel in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, excel, spring-mvc, ms-word

I'm developping a web server based on SpringFramework 4 and I hope to return some files and **open them directly in the browser**.

So far, I succeed to treat PDF by using Header Content-disposition: inline. But it is not working for word/excel. Google Chrome proposes to download the later or download/open by application.

So I hope to know

1. whether or not it's possible to open them directly in the browser
2. if yes, how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know there is no built in Excel viewer for most browsers (IE is different because it is part of Windows, and so is Office). PDF is a different story ... there are loads of plug-ins available.

You might want to consider opening it in google docs, or office.com.

---

Apparently, there is a plugin available for firefox ... http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=27106

BUT that does mean any users will have to have it installed for them to get the behaviour you want!